# Angular favicon.ico is not showing

Tags: angular, favicon

I try to replace my favicon.ico in my angular app. In the code, I can find the right .ico. But the .ico is not showing in the browser (See below).

1. favicon.ico is in my src folder
   https://i.stack.imgur.com/6qh7O.png
2. In my index.html is the following code:

   ```
   <link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="favicon.ico" />
   ```
3. In my angular.json file is this code:

   "assets": ["src/favicon.ico", "src/assets"],
4. When I click on favicon.ico in "Examine", I land on the correct icon. But this is not displayed.
   https://i.stack.imgur.com/yH9LI.png

Do you have any idea what I can do?
Many thanks for your answers in advance.

Comment: Your setup looks correct. It's up to the browser to decide if it shows the favicon. Try bookmarking the page and see if it shows on the bookmark.

Comment: Try Ctrl+Shift + R in the browser

Comment: Ctrl + Shift + R worked for me! The favicon.ico is now displayed. Many thanks for your fast answers.

Answer (score 0):

Are you also having a problem of the correct title not showing in the browser tab? I had a similar issue with my angular project. favicon was not showing up AND browser tab title was not displaying correctly.

The problem seemed to be the fact that I put my angular code in a sub-folder and added a server side redirect pointing to the sub-folder.

To fix this, I deleted the server side redirect and instead added a new index.html file at the root with an html redirect link in it. like this:

```
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0; url=http://example.com/folder" />
```

that fixed both those problems as well as fixing a couple of other problems.